# Probability of ultimate extinction in a Birth and Death process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

The process has infinitely many states, the first one (labelled $0$) absorbing. If $a_n$ is the probability of ultimate extinction given that the process starts in State $n$ (note the corresponding sequence is non-increasing). S. Karlin in his classic book on Stochastic Processes claims that there is a 'simple probabilistic argument' why $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ cannot be a positive number less than $1$ (leaving us with only two possibilities, $0$ and $1$), but does not spell it out (leaving it as an exercise for the reader). What is that argument?

Comment: I think you need to state more assumptions. For instance, why is the sequence non-increasing? Neither this nor the conclusion about the limit is true in the wide generality of "Markov chain with state space $\mathbb N$ where state $0$ is absorbing".

Comment: @ Misha Lavrov: To reach State $0$ from State $n$, the process has to visit State $n-1$ at least once; that's why the probability of the former cannot be bigger than that of the latter.

Comment: So you're assuming that state $n$ can only transition to states $n-1$ or $n+1$?

Comment: Yes, that's the definition of B&D

Comment: In some definitions of birth-death processes, $n$ to $n$ transitions are allowed.

Comment: Not in this case; Karlin's transitions happen at random times, which would make an $n$ to $n$ transition 'invisible'.

Comment: Kolmogorov zero-one law.